# Cyclical vector - Finding the least possible 'cost' (From CodeChef)

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is a question from Codechef but please bear with me.
https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO12004

The contest is for the preparation of the Zonal Computing Olympiad held in India, so its not a competitive contest from which I'd earn something as such. Just need a little help to see what is wrong with my code, because I have a feeling I've overlooked something big and stupid. :P

The problem basically states:

> Imagine there is a vector or array such that the last element is
> linked to the first one. Find the lowest possible sum from adding at
> least one of each adjacent pairs of elements. (refer to link please)
> So answer for {1,2,1,2,2} output would be 4 by adding 1+1+2.

Here is my solution:

Basically what it does is that it iterates backwards, from the end of the vector to the beginning, and stores the lowest possible sum that can be achieved from that vector onwards, in vector M. Done using dynamic programming, basically.

The first two elements of M are the possible answers. Then I do some checks to see which is possible. If M[1] is less than M[0] then the last element of the array/vector should have been included in the sum calculated in M[1].

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
 
#define print(arr) for(auto pos = arr.begin(); pos != arr.end(); ++pos) cout << *pos << " "; cout << endl;
typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
 
 
    int N;
    ll x;
    cin >> N;
    vector <ll> A;
    vector <ll> M(N+2);
    fill(M.begin(),M.end(),0);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        A.push_back(x);
       
    }
 
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        M[i] = A[i]+*min_element(M.begin()+i+1, M.begin()+i+3);
    }
    
    if (M[0] <= M[1]) cout << M[0] << endl;
    else if (M[1] < M[0]) {
        if (M[N-1] <= (M[N-2])) cout << M[1] << endl;
        else cout << M[0] << endl;
    }
 
}
```

However, I could not pass 2 of the test cases in subtask 2. I think the last part of my code is incorrect. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Either that, or I have misunderstood the question. The term "adjacent pairs" is sort of ambiguous. So if there are 4 numbers 3,4,5,6 does adjacent pairs mean adjacent pairs to be {(3,4) (4,5) (5,6) (6,3)} or {either (3,4) and (5,6) or (4,5) and (6,3)}? My code considers the former.

## EDIT:

Thanks a lot @User_Targaryen cleared some doubts about this question! Basically my implementation was the same as yours as my idea behind using dynamic programming was the same. Only that in this case my M (your dp) was the reverse of yours. Anyway I got AC! :) (I had left some silly debugging statements and was wondering for 15 mins what went wrong xD) Updated solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define print(arr) for(auto pos = arr.begin(); pos != arr.end(); ++pos) cout << *pos << " "; cout << endl;
typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;



int main() {


    int N;
    ll x, sum = 0;
    cin >> N;
    vector <ll> A;
    vector <ll> M(N+2);
    fill(M.begin(),M.end(),0);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        A.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        M[i] = A[i]+*min_element(M.begin()+i+1, M.begin()+i+3);
    }

    //print(M);

    reverse(A.begin(), A.end());
    vector <ll> M2(N+2);
    fill(M2.begin(),M2.end(),0);
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        M2[i] = A[i]+*min_element(M2.begin()+i+1, M2.begin()+i+3);
    }
    //print(M2);


    cout << min(M[0], M2[0]) << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: You start your search from the end going right. You can end up with a case where you don't pick the first knight nor the last: N, Y, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N, Y, N. I think if you don't pick a Knight, both adjacent knights *must* be picked. i.e. Y N N Y not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am attaching my accepted solution here:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i,j,k,n;
   cin>>n;
   int a[n],dp1[n],dp2[n];
   int ans;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      cin>>a[i];
      dp1[i]=0;
      dp2[i]=0;
   }
   if(n <= 2)
     cout<< min(a[0],a[1]);

   else{
     i = 2;
     dp1[0] = a[0];
     dp1[1] = a[1];
     while (i < n){
        dp1[i] = a[i] + min(dp1[i-1],dp1[i-2]);
        i = i + 1;
     }

     dp2[0] = a[n-1];
     dp2[1] = a[n-2];
     i = n-3;
     j = 2;
     while(i >= 0){
        dp2[j] = a[i] + min(dp2[j-1],dp2[j-2]);
        i = i - 1;
        j = j + 1;
     }
     ans = min(dp1[n-1], dp2[n-1]);
     cout<<ans;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`dp1[i]` means the most optimal solution till now by including the `i-th` element in the solution

`dp2[i]` means the most optimal solution till now by including the `i-th` element in the solution

`dp1[]` is calculated from left to right, while `dp2[]` is calculated from right to left

The `minimum` of `dp1[n-1]` and `dp2[n-1]` is the final answer.

[image: Solution Report]

**I did your homework!**

**Edit**: *@Alex*: **Dynamic Programming** is something that is very difficult to teach. It is something that comes naturally with some practice. Let us consider my solution (forget about your solution for some time):

`dp1[n-1]` means that I included the last element definitely in the solution, and the constraint that at least one of any 2 adjacent elements need to picked, is satisfied because it always follows:

```
dp1[i] = a[i] + min(dp1[i-1],dp1[i-2]);
```

`dp2[n-1]` means that I included the first element definitely in the solution, and the constraint that at least one of any 2 adjacent elements need to picked, is satisfied also.

So, the minimum of the above two, will give me the final result.

Comment: Heh, thanks! :) So basically if I reverse my vector and do the same process as I have done right now (which is basically what you have also done :P) , I should get the correct answer?

Comment: I understand your point, but what am I doing with my solution then? Now I have reversed the vector A and done the same process but getting even more incorrect subtasks. Any idea why?

Comment: Clarify this line for me `M[i] = A[i]+*min_element(M.begin()+i+1, M.begin()+i+3)` What does it mean? Why are you doing it?

Comment: Its the same as dp1[i] = a[i] + min(dp1[i-1],dp1[i-2]); I'm just a little obsessed with the STL :). Btw finally got AC, thanks! (check edits^)

Answer (score 1):

The idea in your `M[i]` array is "the minimum cost for a solution, assuming the index `i` is included in it".

The condition `if (M[0] <= M[1])` means "if including index 0 is better than not including it, done".

If this condition doesn't hold, then, first of all, the check `if (M[1] < M[0])` is superfluous - remove it. It won't fix any bugs, but will at least reduce confusion.

If the condition is false, you should output `M[1]`, but only if it corresponds to a valid solution. That is, since index 0 is not chosen, the last index should  be chosen. However, with your data structure it's impossible to know whether M[1] corresponds to a solution that chose last index - this information is lost.

To fix this, consider building *two* arrays - add e.g. an array `L` whose meaning is "the minimum cost for a solution, assuming the index `i` is included in it, **and also index `N-1` is included in it**".

Then, at the end of your program, output the minimum of `M[0]` and `L[1]`.

Comment: Hey sounds good! I thought about it too though but I realised what would I do in case both indexes N-1 and N-2 could be included. For example in the case of {1,2,3,1,1}? I should then include the last one, N-1 right?